# Concatenate columns(user selected) and replace them with new column

Tags: vba, excel

I'm not an advanced VBA programmer. I'm working on an excel macro which will allow me to select a range(using input box) to clean the data(makes consistent with mySQL schema) on worksheet. I get this file from anther team and

1.) the order of columns is not fixed

2) levels of categories(there are few columns for categories like level1 level2 etc.) can be anything between 3-10.

I want to concatenate the columns for categories(in image level 1, level 2 etc.) using `|` as a separator and put the values in first category column(level1) while deleting remaining columns(level 2, level 3...[level 10]).

I removed some code from the end to reduce the length here but it still makes sense:

```
Sub cleanData()
Dim rngMyrange As Range
Dim cell As Range
On Error Resume Next
    Do
        'Cleans Status column
        Set rngMyrange = Application.InputBox _
            (Prompt:="Select Status column", Type:=8)
            On Error GoTo 0
            'Is a range selected? Exit sub if not selected
            If rngMyrange Is Nothing Then
                End
                Else
                Exit Do
            End If
    Loop
        With rngMyrange 'with the range just selected
            .Replace What:="Dead", Replacement:="Inactive", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False
            'I do more replace stuff here
        End With
    rngMyrange.Cells(1, 1) = "Status"

Do
        'Concatenates Category Columns
        Set rngMyrange = Application.InputBox _
            (Prompt:="Select category columns", Type:=8)
            On Error GoTo 0
            'Is a range selected? Exit sub if not selected
            If rngMyrange Is Nothing Then
                End
                Else
                Exit Do
            End If
    Loop
        With rngMyrange 'with the range just selected
            'Need to concatenate the selected columns(row wise)
        End With
    rngMyrange.Cells(1, 1) = "Categories"
End Sub
```

[image: Illustration]
Please do not suggest a UDF,  I want to do this with macro.  I must do this on files before importing them on SQL database, so a macro will be handy. Please ask if I failed to mention anything else.

**EDIT: Image attached for illustration**

***UPDATE:***
I now have a working code with help from vaskov17 on mrexcel but it does not delete the columns from where the levels are picked-level 2, level 3...etc. to shift next columns to left and the major challenge for me is to implement that code in my existing macro using range type instead of long type. I do not want to enter start column and finish column separately, instead I should be able to select range like in my original macro. Code for that macro is below, please help me:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim start As Long
    Dim finish As Long
    Dim c As Long
    Dim r As Long
    Dim txt As String

    start = InputBox("Enter start column:")
    finish = InputBox("Enter ending column:")

    For r = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For c = start To finish
            If Cells(r, c).Text <> "" Then
                txt = txt & Cells(r, c).Text & "|"
                Cells(r, c).Clear
            End If
        Next

        If Right(txt, 1) = "|" Then
            txt = Left(txt, Len(txt) - 1)
        End If

        Cells(r, start) = txt
        txt = ""
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Mind leaving a comment for down-voting? If you are too smart to think that its a dumb question, why can't you tell so that I can improve it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @mehow: updated question with image for illustration and progress on the matter. Please advise if it is still unclear.

Comment: are the columns always named `Level1` to `Level5`?

Comment: @mehow:The columns are always named in same fashion from `level 1-level 10`.  `level 1-level 3` will always exist but ending level can be anything between `level 3-level 10`, i.e., there will be at least 3 such columns and at most 10 such columns.

Comment: u realize that someone can mess the spreadsheet up if the wrong range is selected? are you going to be selecting entire columns or just specific range ( with fixed rows )?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have removed the inputbox for selection of the category columns. Since they are always named Level `x`»`y` it makes it easier to find them automatically. That's why  added a `FindColumns()` Sub to your code. It assigns the first `fCol` and last `lCol` Category column to global variables.

The `ConcatenateColumns()` concatenates cells in each row using "|" as separator.

The `DeleteColumns()` deletes the other columns

`Cells(1, fCol).Value = "Category` renames `Level 1` to `Category` and `Columns.AutoFit` resizes all columns widths to fit the text.

**<kbd>Code</kbd>**:

```
Option Explicit

Dim fCol As Long, lCol As Long

Sub cleanData()
    Dim rngMyrange As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    On Error Resume Next
        Do
            'Cleans Status column
            Set rngMyrange = Application.InputBox _
                (Prompt:="Select Status column", Type:=8)
                On Error GoTo 0
                'Is a range selected? Exit sub if not selected
                If rngMyrange Is Nothing Then
                    End
                    Else
                    Exit Do
                End If
        Loop
            With rngMyrange 'with the range just selected
                .Replace What:="Dead", Replacement:="Inactive", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False
                'I do more replace stuff here
            End With
        rngMyrange.Cells(1, 1) = "Status"

        ' Concatenate Category Columns
        FindColumns
        ConcatenateColumns
        DeleteColumns

        Cells(1, fCol).Value = "Category"
        Columns.AutoFit
End Sub

Private Sub FindColumns()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    For i = 1 To ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        If StrComp(ws.Cells(1, i).Text, "Level 1", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            For j = i To ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                If InStr(1, ws.Cells(1, j).Text, "Level", vbTextCompare) Then
                    lCol = j
                End If
            Next j
            fCol = i
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next i
End Sub

Private Sub ConcatenateColumns()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    For i = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, fCol).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng = Cells(i, fCol)
        For j = fCol + 1 To lCol
            rng = rng & "|" & Cells(i, j)
        Next j
        rng = "|" & rng & "|"
        Set rng = Nothing
    Next i
End Sub

Private Sub DeleteColumns()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = lCol To fCol + 1 Step -1
        Columns(i).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Superb. works flawlessly. Are there any performance constraints? There is no error checking, I hope it won't break in any special case.

Comment: this code is supposed to help you get started with your project. error handling and testing its something you will have to do on your own. I dont have the time for it and trust me its a time consuming task to debug-test code and check for most awkward situations and how to handle them etc. you can post the code at the [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) and maybe someone will have time to give you tips etc

Comment: Can you please update the code to add a "|" at the beginning and end of text as well. for example: `|communication|antenna|internal|`

Comment: I was just too excited about this code that I went to test it.  I just came back to accept it now. :D  I'll do the error checking myself so far, performance looks fine,  i need to test it on large data.

Comment: You can always add the `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` to speed up a bit. I dont think you will find/write much faster code than what I wrote here. It should be fast and efficient

Comment: Yes, i have already added `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` in my main macro.